# How to access columns by column index?

Tags: java, jtable

```
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) 
    {            
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return (String) columnNames[col];
        }
    };

   table = new JTable(model); 

   for (int tc=0; tc<table.getColumnCount(); tc++)
        table.getColumn(tc).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaRenderer());
```

I need to access columns by column index. The following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Identifier not found
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumnIndex(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getColumn(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use column name to get the column, as the following:

```
 for (int tc=0; tc<table.getColumnCount(); tc++)
        table.getColumn(columnNames[tc]).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaRenderer());
```

Answer (score 0):

TableColumnModel has getColumn(int columnIndex) method:

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
for (int tc = 0; tc < table.getColumnCount(); tc++)
    columnModel.getColumn(tc).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaRenderer());
```